# Растянуть div-блок по содержимому

Tags: контент, html, блок

Здравствуйте.
Как собственно можно растянуть div-блок по его содержимому.
Пробовал вот это варимнт, но не получилось:

```
 <div style="clear:both;">
 содержимое
 </div>
```

Comment: [Попробуй почитать здесь](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/css/136622/)

Comment: добавьте в вопрос побольше контекста

Comment: Да, в какой-то степени это помогло для достижения общей цели... 

Спасибо =)

Answer (score 1):

Используйте этот код:

```
<div style="display:inline-block;">
    содержимое
</div>
```